# Response returned html instead of json in Java when string was given numeric value

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey

I tried to send an object through the below code, I have handled the client and webtarget part of code outside the function.

```
public Result setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
        if(userDetails.getAge()==null||userDetails.getId()==null||userDetails.getname()==null) {
            return new Result(201,"null fields","objects field cannot be null","null filed");
        }else {
            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
            Response response  = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(userDetails, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            String jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);
//          System.out.println(jsonResponse);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Result result = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Result.class);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

The object had basic properties but all were string as shown below in `UserDetails` class

```
package com.jay;

public class UserDetails {

    String id;
    String name;
    String age;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public UserDetails(String id, String name, String age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public UserDetails() {
        super();
    }
}
```

When I tried to send jaydev as age value like this

```
UserDetails insertUser = new UserDetails("31211","jay_dev","jaydev");

Result postResult = clientSidedRequest.setUserDetails(insertUser);
```

I got the response in the form of html instead of json where as both client and server the `userdetails` class has the same datatype for the fields ie `string`

the `jsonResponse` was filled with html data instead of string.

I don't understand why this happened, as I am new to this. Also there was no error just that I could not deserialize the `jsonResponse`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://192.168.1.22:8080/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I get when I print the `jsonResponse` and I get error when I try to deserialize using gson

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at com.jay.ClientSidedRequest.setUserDetails(ClientSidedRequest.java:49)
    at com.jay.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: could you please share the output also for other to verify your response

Comment: You're getting an error page from the server. Check the serve logs for any exceptions. If none show, use a generic ExceptionMapper to try to log any swallowed exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

when you send the data from the client application, make sure you have the http header

> Content-Type: application/json

And also annotate your request handling method with

> ```
> @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
> @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
> ```